# Need to work through an array from bottom of nest upwards

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

OK, I have created an array that is similar to this:

```
[household] => Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'A Nother'
            [parent] => 
            [bank] => Array
                (
                    [balance] => 23745.98
                    [debit] => 14009
                    [trans] => 103
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [4567] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 'M Claus'
                            [parent] => 1234
                            [bank] => Array
                                (
                                    [balance] => 858
                                    [debit] => 543
                                    [trans] => 5
                                )

                            [children] => 
                        )

                    [7890] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 'S Claus'
                            [parent] => 1234
                            [bank] => Array
                                (
                                    [balance] => 1302
                                    [debit] => 708
                                    [trans] => 6
                                )

                            [children] => 
                        )

                    [2335] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 'Elf 1'
                            [parent] => 1234
                            [bank] => Array
                                (
                                    [balance] => 2315
                                    [debit] => 1221
                                    [trans] => 13
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [2896] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 'Snowman'
                                            [parent] => 2335
                                            [bank] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [balance] => 486
                                                    [debit] => 252
                                                    [trans] => 4
                                                )

                                            [children] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1142] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 'Grinch'
                            [parent] => 1234
                            [genone] => Array
                                (
                                    [bank] => 2042
                                    [debit] => 1212
                                    [trans] => 12
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [8854] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => 'Fill ER Up'
                                            [upline] => 1142
                                            [bank] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [balance] => 139
                                                    [debit] => 101
                                                    [trans] => 1
                                                )

                                            [children] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My issue is that I need to get to the grandchild element, process it, then walk upwards through the parent all the way up to the root. However I need to come up each "leg" and process all of these sequentially before processing the respective parent.

There could be up to 10 nestings within this, and the values of each processing will need to be passed in to the parent calculation. So in this example, take the balance of all children and add that to the balance of the parent for a family balance if that makes sense, and then those amounts being passed to the grandparent to make a household balance. Everything I can find simply reverses the array, and I can hard code so that it starts at third nesting but I wanted the code to be *future proof* and not have that kind of limitation. I KNOW there must be a solution that is elegant, hopefully somebody on here can point me at it :) TIA.

Comment: Unless you can create a concise example with a desired output, its going to be really hard to help here. Why do you want to iterate in reverse - the tree structure is designed to flow from trunk to leaves not the other way

Comment: The desired output is (to use a household/family example) figure grandchilds balances and store these, then add those balance(s) to the parents balance and display the family unit balance. Then to combine siblings and add those to grandparents balance to display household balance.

Comment: imho..I think its better to redesign the source that produces this array...the further it extends, the harder to get it organize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to traverse the array from the bottom to the top. Tree's are not capable of such.

Instead, create a recursive function, and iterate through every person.

```
$householdBalance = 0;
$household = ...;
foreach ($array as &$person) {
    // The "&" symbol is to allow us to modify the array. It creates a reference to $person.
    $familyBalance = getBalanceOfFamily($person);
    $householdBalance += $familyBalance;

    // This will store the total balance which includes the person's children, grandchildren...
    $person['family_balance'] = $familyBalance;
}
$household['balance'] = $householdBalance;

function getBalanceOfFamily(&$person) {
    $familyBalance = $person['bank']['balance'];
    // other calculations

    foreach ($person['children'] as &$child) {
        $balanceOfChildsFamily = getBalanceOfFamily($child);
        $familyBalance += $balanceOfChildsFamily;
    }
    return $familyBalance;
}
```

This will iterate through the first people in the array. Then, for the children, it will call `getBalanceOfFamily`, and will return the total balance of the entire family.

Comment: Thank you - this makes complete sense and also means I can move some of the heavy lifting down to this set of functions. My initial array is now simply a list of ids and relationships, then I have modified your suggestion to retrieve the values as needed. Not only does it work, but my code is cleaner and about twice as fast to generate the results :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic recursive function, that will do exactly what you are looking for.

```
function proccessArray($arrayData){
    foreach($arrayData as $data){
        if(count($data['children'])){
            $childData = proccessArray($data['children']);
        }

        // do some calculations

        return $calculatedData;

    }
}
```